# A person full of sin

Tags: riddle

*I was born in the 90s.*

*People love me even though I am full of sin.*

*Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed who I am.*

*I cannot change even if the punishment is as severe as chopping off both my arms*

***Who am I?***

Hint 1:

> I am alphanumeric.

Hint 2:

> I was born in 1995.

Comment: Are you a 90s rapper? You sound like a rapper. Cause you pretty damn clever with you rhymes and you wrote some nice lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is:

> Se7en (the movie)

I was born in the 90s.

> This movie was from 1995

People love me even though I am full of sin.

> The movie was about the 7 deadly sins

Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed who I am.

> In the movie, the villain killed 5 victims based on 5 of the 7 deadly sins, leaving the last 2 sins (envy and wrath) to a twist ending (I won't spoil it here)

I cannot change even if the punishment is as severe as chopping off both my arms

> (Thanks to Stiv): If you remove the left and right parts of the title ("Se" and "en"), you are left with "7" which is the same title

Hint 1: I am alphanumeric.

> "Se7en" has both letters and numbers

Hint 2: I was born in 1995.

> The movie was from 1995

Comment: I think you've got it! But 'chopping off both my arms' will refer to removing the start and end of the name...

Comment: @JS1 Wow. I never thought someone would solve it! Well done. Committing couple of crimes less would have been rot13(5 naq vg'f ebzna rdhvinyrag jbhyq unir orra I. Fr7ra gura jbhyq unir orra FrIra). That was my thought process while framing the question. But your explanation holds true as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure I got it:

> You are Heroin ($C_{21}H_{23}NO_{5}$)

I was born in the 90s:

> "*In 1895, Bayer marketed diacetylmorphine as an over-the-counter drug under the trademark name Heroin*" - from Wikipedia (90s doesn´t necessarily mean the 1990s)

People love me even though I am full of sin:

> People take it even though they know its bad for them.

Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed who I am:

> less people taking Heroin wouldn´t change its chemical composure.

I cannot change even if the punishment is as severe as chopping off both my arms:

> I am not that deep into chemistry, but the chemical composure of Heroin (upper picture) looks like it has two arms and when you take them away the chemical composure looks like Morphine (lower picture) which is also a drug. [image: Heroin] [image: Morphine]

Comment: Your answer satisfies all the criteria except for "Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed who I am". There should be a couple (two) of crimes less. I really appreciate your thinking but this was not the intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try. Are you, per chance...

> A Tamagotchi? Probably Nyorotchi, this one https://tamagotchi.fandom.com/wiki/Nyorotchi

I was born in the 90s.

> Tamagotchis were born in the 90s

People love me even though I am full of sin.

> Nyorotchi resembles a snake, which is the encarnation of sin in the holy bible. Nevertheless you still take care of him and give him food/cleaning

Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed who I am.

> To evolve to Nyorotchi a tamagotchi baby needs to have plenty of failures, comitting two or three less when you're locked into Nyorotchi, does not matter, you'll get him anyways.

I cannot change even if the punishment is as severe as chopping off both my arms

> Well, this is the part I cant figure, but I guess is as simple as that Nyorotchi does not have arms, actually he has a tail.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. I learnt something new. The answer I am looking for has arms though.

Answer (score -3):

As nobody answered yet, I'll have a go.

> The HIV.

> The pandemic started in the 80s but really took off in the 90s.

> Some people loved it because it had a reputation for killing only homosexuals and heroin addicts.

> Committing a couple of crimes less wouldn't have changed what it was.

> If the parts of a virus which allow it to bind to cells are its arms, then the treatment chopped them off. The virus hasn't been able to mutate to evade the treatment (and I hope it never will!).